# Magento Adding a Block to an index Action Page

Tags: magento

I am creating a module that will have its own page at mysite.com/memymodule/index/index

I want to add functionality from a template file from at templates/me/template.phtml

I have an index controller like this:

```
<?php
    class me_mymodule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {        

        public function indexAction() {

            $this->loadLayout();     
            $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
?>
```

I have a layout update mymodule.xml that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <mymodule_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="me.mymodule" template="me/template.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </mymodule_index_index>
</layout>
```

The frontName of the module is mymodule

When the page renders the content block is completely empty and the content of template.phtml is completely ignored.

Help much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Code within your Controller's Action -

```
 var_dump(Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->getUpdate()->getHandles());

 exit("Your Layout Path is ".__LINE__." in ".__FILE__);
```

This code tells you about the Tag which you need to create within Layout.xml.

Also check **Config.xml** that the **Layout Update** Section is correctly defined or not.

Hope it'll be beneficial for you.

THANKS

Comment: Thanks, I get "array(0) { }"  Not sure what that means......

I know that the update section is OK in the config.xml because when I update <default> the changes can be seen across the site.  It is only when I change to <mymodule_index_index> that nothing can be seen.

Comment: Ignore that, I get it now, I had removed the two pieces of layout code.  It works thanks and always great to learn a new function like that :-)

Comment: So what is the problem maker and what is the solution?